# shell script to match the column value and count the no of rows with the first match line

Tags: shell

Sample file: `list.txt`

```
ABC|DEF|March11,2017|11:00|1
ABC|DEF|March11,2017|11:10|1
ABC|DEF|March11,2017|11:20|0
DEF|TRO|March11,2017|11:30|0
DEF|TRO|March11,2017|11:40|1
DEF|TRO|March11,2017|11:50|0
RFR|TRO|March11,2017|12:00|0
DAEF|TRO|March11,2017|12:10|4
DSDEF|TRO|March11,2017|12:20|2
DScEF|TRO|March11,2017|12:30|1
DCDEF|TRO|March11,2017|12:40|0
DE34F|TRO|March11,2017|12:50|0
DESDF|TRO|March11,2017|13:00|0
```

I want to count the rows if `$5` position `ne 0` until the `$5` becomes 0 by print the first matching line (`$0`) in shell

Ex : o/p should be

```
ABC|DEF|March11,2017|11:00|1 - 2(rows) 
DEF|TRO|March11,2017|11:40|1 - 1 (rows)
DAEF|TRO|March11,2017|12:10|4 - 3(rows)
```

Comment: What have you tried?  How did it fail?

Comment: The output expected makes no logic.